# Error -104 Unexpected end of command creating a Firebird stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird, firebird2.5

I want to create a stored procedure in Firebird:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE CalcPvIncome
 ( BeginDate date,
   EndDate   date,
   KwPrice   decimal (2,2) ) 
   
RETURNS ( Total_PV_Production decimal (9,2),
          Total_Income decimal (9,2) )
AS
BEGIN
  
   FOR SELECT SUM(ENERGY/1000), SUM((ENERGY/1000) * :KwPrice) 
       FROM PVPROD 
       WHERE proddate >= :BeginDate AND proddate <= :Enddate 
       INTO :Total_PV_Production , :Total_Income
       DO
       
       BEGIN
        SUSPEND ;
       END
END
```

I get this error:

> Engine Code : 335544569
>
> Engine Message : Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Unexpected end of command - line 18, column 9

The SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(ENERGY/1000) AS Total_PV_Production, 
   sum((ENERGY/1000)*0.55) as Total_Income
FROM 
   PVPROD 
where  
   proddate >= '12.06.2012' and  proddate <= '12.07.2012'
```

Comment: **WHAT** errors are you getting!?!?!?

Answer (score 6):

You have to add `SET TERM` statement before and after the stored procedure. It is used to change the "terminator character". Here's an example:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE CalcPvIncome
( BeginDate date,
  EndDate   date,
  KwPrice   decimal (2,2) ) 

RETURNS ( Total_PV_Production decimal (9,2),
          Total_Income decimal (9,2) )
AS
BEGIN
  ...
END

SET TERM ; ^
```

Note that default terminator is `^` and also note that you are setting `;` as new terminator before and resetting it back to `^` after stored procedure declaration.