# Firebird EXECUTE BLOCK throwing error 104 from c# and Flamerobin

Tags: c#, sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a couple of queries that I want to execute withing an `EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN ... END` statement.

So I go on trying with my first entry - script looks pretty simple:

```
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID, VALUE) VALUES ('1', 'First Entry');
```

So I run this and all works fine. Next I put it into an execute block:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK AS
BEGIN
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID, VALUE) VALUES ('1', 'First Entry');
END
```

And now, I get an error `104 isc_dsql_prepare failed` error on line 3 at the `;` character: `Unexpected end of command  - line 4, column 70`. When I run in FlameRobin, I get the same error, but it all works just fine when I execute this exact same code in DBWorkbench...

Can anyone explain what could be the issue?

**UPDATE**
Here how I execute the block via C#:

```
 string sql = "EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN .... END";
 DbLive.Open();
 FbCommand command = new FbCommand(sql, DbLive);
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: If you use `execute block` from flame robin, you need to use `set term` to change the statement terminator (same as you need to do when creating stored procedures); as for C#, it will depend on **how** you execute it, so please post the C# code you use to execute it.

Comment: I see you have edited your question to fix your syntax error, but that invalidates part of my current answer. I have considered to rollback your edit. Could you please edit your question and post the full C# code you use and the complete error you get. I have tested your code (and replaced the `execute block as begin ... end` with the block posted separately in your question and that works.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel indeed I'm actually checking the original command... For sure, I've made a type as I use `UPDATE OR INSERT` not `INSERT OR UPDATE`, but I still have the problem...!

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ok I've finally made the test and found that indeed setting `SET TERM ^^ ;` in FlameRobin solves the problem. However, now my C# code complains as `SET TERM` is not a recognized syntax....

Comment: That is because `set term` is not part of the Firebird statement syntax; it is specific to query tools like ISQL and flame robin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I required 2 steps to fix the problem:

1) use `ExecuteScalar` in the C# code:

```
string sql = "EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN .... END";
DbLive.Open();
FbCommand command = new FbCommand(sql, DbLive);
command.ExecuteScalar();
```

2) No use of `SET TERM` at all but instead, making sure that the size of the block isn't too large. A simple test on the `sql` string size was sufficient (credits to [Elias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3600623/elias) thanks to the comment in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23841721/2490877)).

**UPDATE**
After upgrading to the latest Firebird provider (as for the time of writing, it is v.5.7.0.0), both `ExecuteScalar` and `ExecuteNonQuery` work.

Also note that because of lots of triggers, I made the intelligence of the size test to include both `sql` length as stated, but also added a query counter, to limit the both the length of the block and the number of queries.

Comment: Weird for me `ExecuteNonQuery()` works. Which version of the Firebird ado.net provider are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient Runtime version v4.0.30319, Version 4.7.0.0

Comment: You could try upgrading to 5.6.0.0

Comment: Ok just upgraded. Unfortunately, I realized that `FbScript` is no longer working if the first line is a comment (a side note, though - it doesn't affect the result). No indeed, whether I use `ExecuteNonQuery` or `ExecuteScalar`, it works... Weird, but good to now. So which one should I actually use now???

Comment: newer is usually better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use the execute block as posted earlier combined with the C# code block, then you actually have two distinct errors, one in Flame Robin (an *Unexpected end of command*), and one in C# (a *Token unknown or*).

The problem in Flame Robin can be solved by adding `set term #;` at the start to switch statement terminators. Currently Flame Robin interprets the `;` inside the execute block as a signal to send the statement to the server. See also [Error -104 Unexpected end of command creating a Firebird stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586075/error-104-unexpected-end-of-command-creating-a-firebird-stored-procedure)

If you do this you will then get the same error as in your C# code:

> An unhandled exception of type 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException' occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll
> Additional information: Dynamic SQL Error
> SQL error code = -104
> Token unknown - line 1, column 31
> or

The reason for this error is that there is no DML statement starting with `insert or update` in Firebird, instead you should use [`update or insert`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-update-or-insert) (or [`merge`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-merge)).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Why is it that the command works outside the `EXECUTE BLOCK` then...??? I've tried, it worked just fine, my row was inserted etc...

Comment: @neggenbe I'll check, but I'd expect that to give the same error.

Comment: @neggenbe I have just tested it, but outside of the execute block, use of `insert or update` (instead of `update or insert`) as a normal statement yields exactly the same exception (Firebird 3.0.0 and 2.5.6, Firebird .net provider 5.6.0).