# Firebird trigger before update (update column with timestamp)

Tags: sql, firebird

I'd like to create trigger in firebird, that will before update set LAST_UPDATE to current timestamp and SYNC to 0. But I'm getting error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TELEFONI_CISLA_before_update FOR TELEFONI_CISLA
ACTIVE
BEFORE UPDATE
AS BEGIN
NEW.LAST_UPDATE = (select cast('NOW' as timestamp) from rdb$database);
NEW.SYNC = 0;
END
```

Error:

```
> Error: *** IBPP::SQLException *** Context: Statement::Prepare( CREATE
> TRIGGER TELEFONI_CISLA_before_update FOR TELEFONI_CISLA ACTIVE BEFORE
> UPDATE AS BEGIN NEW.LAST_UPDATE = (select cast('NOW' as timestamp)
> from rdb$database) ) Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed
> 
> SQL Message : -104 Invalid token
> 
> Engine Code    : 335544569 Engine Message : Dynamic SQL Error SQL
> error code = -104 Unexpected end of command - line 5, column 69
```

Comment: Please provide all relevant information. What error do you get, and provide a [mre]. Asking if somebody can help you is not how you ask for help on Stack Overflow, instead ask a specific question. See also [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). But to give you hint, look at the select syntax inside a stored procedure, in fact, that select is entirely unnecessary. You can do `NEW.LAST_UPDATE = cast('NOW' as timestamp);` instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited it. Also tried your hint, but still doesn't work (still same error code).

Comment: What tool are you using to execute this? Judging by the error, it looks like you need to switch statement terminators, because right now your tool is sending an incomplete statement (until the first `;` it encountered). Depending on the tool you might need to something like `set term #;` before `create trigger`.

Comment: `now` should be `current_timestamp`, e.g.: `new.last_update = current_timestamp;`. But it most probably is indeed the tool messing up the `,` - the code (after fixing the `now` thing) works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=f10decf97a05ee7b99e33d227a90715a

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There is a minor difference between using `cast('NOW' as timestamp)` and `current_timestamp`. `current_timestamp` is stable for the duration of a transaction (or at least a statement execution, I always forget this), while `cast('NOW' as timestamp)` should yield the actual current time at the time the cast is evaluated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Error -104 Unexpected end of command creating a Firebird stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586075/error-104-unexpected-end-of-command-creating-a-firebird-stored-procedure)

Comment: There is no need for the explicit cast, `NEW.LAST_UPDATE = 'NOW'` is enough.